# Как создать новый экземпляр класса из строки?

Tags: php, namespace, классы

Нужно примерно так:

```
$obj = new \namespace\$className(...);
```

Проблема в том, что php ругается на `\namespace\`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$className = '\namespace\\' . $className;
$instance = new $className;
```